# Java Script button in lightning configuration conversion error

Tags: javascript

While converting Java Script button i am getting below error message.

> Something went wrong with the deployment. Component:
> LCC_Confirm_Shipment_Scheduled_Event_cController. Problem:
> ESLINT_ERROR: {c:LCC_Confirm_Shipment_Scheduled_Event_c - CONTROLLER}
> line:col [4:12] --> Parsing error: Identifier directly after number.

[image][image]

Conversion type says Lightning Component Full but when converting getting above error.

I have attached file with screenshot.

```js
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/23.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")}


if('{!Scheduled_Event__c.Shipment_Status__c}' == 'Cancelled')
{
alert("Shipment is already Cancelled.");
}
else if('{!Scheduled_Event__c.Cancellation_Reason__c}' === '' )
{
alert("Please provide a cancellation reason before cancelling the shipment.");
}
else
{
var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel the shipment schedule?\n This action cannot be undone.");

if (r==true)
{
try
{
var msg = sforce.apex.execute("TMS_RemoteActions","cancelShipment",
{id:'{!Scheduled_Event__c.Id}'});
if(msg=='')
window.location.reload();
else
alert("Error cancelling shipment.\n\n" + msg);
}
catch(err)
{
var txt="Error cancelling shipment.\n\n";
txt+="Error description: " + err + "\n\n";
alert(txt);
}

}
}
```

---

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does it get to generate the LC code?

Comment: @AlbaRivas No it didn't generated LC code.